# C++ char array value assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm trying to keep the alphabet in a char array. But 4 letters show absurd charachters.

I run the program step by step using F11 button. Wrote the alphabet and after 'Q', until 'V' whatever I write, it shows ...PQÿÿÿÿVWXYZ  this character: 'ÿ'

```
    int main()
    {   
    cout << "ALPHABET:";
    char alf[] = "";
    cin >> alf;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
```

I expect: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Actual result: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQÿÿÿÿVWXYZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with this line:

```
char alf[] = "";
```

you declare char array with size 1 which can only hold empty strings (null terminator). Note that `std::istream::operator>>` with `char *` does not validate size of array (it cannot) so you are getting Undefined Behavior writing into array with out of bounds. Solution is to use `std::string` instead which will grow as needed.

```
int main()
{   
    std::cout << "ALPHABET:";
    std::string alf;
    std::cin >> alf;
    std::cout << alf << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It probably should be at least 27 as you need null terminator, but I would not recommend to use char array with >> as it leads to unsafe programs that vulnerable to buffer overflow, do not make such habit.

Comment: I have a function which has a parameter char*. So I can't use string

Comment: @Slava - correction. It (operator>>) **could** have a separate overload for C-style arrays. It doesn't, though.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukSarıışık you should be able to use `std::string` and pass those functions the pointer to underlying char buffer you can get with `c_str()`

Comment: @SergeyA even with that overload it would only work in some cases, anyway lets say it cannot in the form it is written.

Comment: @SergeyA I tried it. If I remember correctly, there was an error about using const char*

Comment: @ÖmerFarukSarıışık does that function modify char array passed to it?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukSarıışık At this point, you need to give us more details about the function you are using

Comment: @ÖmerFarukSarıışık [`alf.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) returns a non-const `char*` in C++17 and later. Otherwise, you can use `&alf[0]` (technically, not guaranteed to produce a pointer to null-terminated sequential memory before C++11, but usually works on most implementations). Otherwise, you can `const_cast` away the `const` from `alf.c_str()` (if you don't modify the data being pointed to)

Comment: I tried `c_str()` and `data()` but still same error.